# Unable to install poppler library

Tags: python, pip, conda, anaconda3

I am trying to install poppler. Its a requirement for one of the projects: https://github.com/idea-fasoc/datasheet-scrubber/tree/master/src/table_extraction

Every time I try in Anaconda Prompt, I get this error.
The `conda` command doesn't resolve the environment, hence I tried using `pip`

I installed `cmake`. I also installed it via VS installer.
This is the error I am still getting. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```py
(base) C:\Windows\System32>pip install python-poppler
Collecting python-poppler
  Using cached python-poppler-0.3.0.tar.gz (823 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: python-poppler
  Building wheel for python-poppler (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [103 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\destination.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\document.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\embeddedfile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\font.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\page.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\pagerenderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\pagetransition.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\toc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\utilities.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler\cpp
      copying src\poppler\cpp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler\cpp
      running egg_info
      writing src\python_poppler.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\python_poppler.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\python_poppler.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\python_poppler.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'src\python_poppler.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py:32: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        cmake_version = LooseVersion(
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31942.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31942.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- pybind11 v2.9.2
      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe (found version "3.9.13")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/libs/python39.lib
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
      CMake Error at C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
        Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
        C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:99 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
        CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/halda/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-onyki_zr/python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-39/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 76, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build.py", line 24, in run
          super().run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 39, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 68, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\\poppler\\cpp', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\\poppler\\cpp', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-poppler
  Running setup.py clean for python-poppler
Failed to build python-poppler
Installing collected packages: python-poppler
  Running setup.py install for python-poppler ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-poppler did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [107 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\destination.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\document.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\embeddedfile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\font.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\image.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\page.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\pagerenderer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\pagetransition.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\rectangle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\toc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\utilities.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      copying src\poppler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler\cpp
      copying src\poppler\cpp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\poppler\cpp
      running egg_info
      writing src\python_poppler.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\python_poppler.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src\python_poppler.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\python_poppler.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'src\python_poppler.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py:32: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        cmake_version = LooseVersion(
      -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
      -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.20348.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
      -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31942.0
      -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31942.0
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- pybind11 v2.9.2
      -- Found PythonInterp: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe (found version "3.9.13")
      -- Found PythonLibs: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/libs/python39.lib
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG
      -- Performing Test HAS_MSVC_GL_LTCG - Success
      CMake Error at C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
        Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
        C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:99 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
        CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/halda/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-onyki_zr/python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-39/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 76, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 692, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build.py", line 24, in run
          super().run()
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 992, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 39, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\halda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-onyki_zr\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\setup.py", line 68, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\\poppler\\cpp', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\halda\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-onyki_zr\\python-poppler_a0472eeab1dd487f8486d308273da89b\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\\poppler\\cpp', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-poppler

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Edit: Updating the error I get even after installing the `cmake`

Answer (score 1):

like the line

```
RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: poppler.cpp.modules
```

says I would try to install cmake and then run it again

you can install it via

```
pip install cmake
```

Comment: Sorry, I did install it but forgot to update the error message. Here's what I get now